# What is te best way to function-strip-clone an object in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a JS class which I use as a wrapper around some data:

```
function _item(){
 this.property1="hi";
 this.property2={
  another:"object"
 }
 this.somefunction=function(){
  //do stuff
 }
}
```

The primary purpose of the class is to store and provide some helper functions to the underlying data; but the class purposely has no state information that isn't stored with the data.

To upload the data to a NOSQL database, we can't have the functions sticking around. So, currently, I'm using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object))` to strip the functions.

However I don't think this is the best way of doing that. Is there any other faster or more convenient way to do it?

Comment: Do you have to store functions in each object? I.e. do different objects have different functions? Because if the functions are all the same, you can just inherit them.

Comment: yeah nah yeah i don't want to store the functions in each object. In fact, I SPECIFICALLY dont want the functions in the objects, because when uploading to my NOSQL database it rejects any objects which have functions. The functions and classes are fine - it's down to how to deep clone the object without functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write your own JS code to do exactly the same thing, it I doubt it would be as efficient as the built-in function.

See: https://jsperf.com/json-stringify-versions/3

[image]

Comment: Neat. I'd accept your answer but I feel like some mod is going to complain about 'you just provided a link'

Comment: I know :( In this case, link is evidence, not a solution. Sample added.